# how to resolve `member method [java.lang.Object, add/1] not found` in painless

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to calculate (1 / num + 1) by using painless.
When num is 0, the whole result should be null.
I wrote like this;

```
POST /_scripts/painless/_execute
{
  "script": {
    "source":  """
      (
        params.num == 0 ? null : BigDecimal.valueOf(1).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(params.num))
      ).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1))
    """,
    "params": {"num": 1}
  }
}
```

But I got a compile error:

```
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason" : "member method [java.lang.Object, add/1] not found"
}
```

How to resolve this?
I want to write this code by one-liner if possible (so I don't want to use if statement).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `add()` *inside* the brackets.

```
(
    params.num == 0 ? null : BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(params.num).add(BigDecimal.ONE))
)
```

You were calling `add()` on the result of the expression, which has type `Object`.

Note also the use of `BigDecimal.ONE` in preference to `BigDecimal.valuesOf(1)`